# Mirrors and light beam divergence technology limits

Tags: astronomy, electromagnetic-radiation, propulsion, solar-system-exploration, experimental-technology

There are many applications for orbital space mirrors in astronomy (better telescopes) and space propulsion (solar power for deep space probes), but this is limited by the minimum beam divergence achievable with current technology

So, i'm trying to understand what physical and technological limits exists in our capacity to build mirrors that can keep as small beam divergence as possible. For instance, a sail probe to Saturn would require that the beam doesn't significantly diverge above 300m-600m (the biggest sail we can conceive of building in the inmediate future) at distances as big as 5-6 AU ($10^{11} - 10^{13}$ meters)

What is the best beam focusing divergence we can achieve for solar light with mirrors *right now*, and what limits the improvement of this? technological limits? fundamental physical limits?

**Edit** let's assume the concrete case of a wavelength of $10^{-6}$ meters, and a distance of $10^{12}$ meters (Neptune orbit). Can't i, for instance, build a focusing element with a focal length of $10^{12}$ meters that would push the far field beam divergence at farther distances from the focal point? Is this a manufacturing limitation of focusing element engineering (not enough precision to build lens made of atoms with the required focal length), or something more instrinsic, say, a focal point cannot be farther than some finite distance that depends on the wavelength?

Comment: This is not a technological limitation. Beam divergenceis llimited by diffraction. The minimum divergenceis dictated by wwavelength and beam diameter.

Comment: what is 'beam diameter'? you mean that a bigger mirror will have smaller divergence? is there a formula for that?

Comment: A number of random comments here. First, you claim a particular limit on the size of the sail---well, I can *conceive* of a lot---I assume you've based this on something like the areal density and the current single payload lift limits. It might help us to know what you think causes the limit. Second, ideally you'd like a spot size comparable to the sail size, but there is nothing to stop you using it even when the spot is "too big", you just get lower thrust.

Comment: Third, Forward suggested a big Fresnel lens rather than a mirror in his Rocheworld books, which might be easier in-so-far as the focusing element is under less thrust and half of it can be empty space which should nearly double it's area for a given mass.

Comment: @dmckee, understood, but in this case the question is strictly for mirrors only. The limits on areal density are just about manufacturing and logistic limits. Something bigger than 1Km in radius becomes troublesome to manufacture and deploy from our current cargo lifting vehicles. I'm just trying to get a sense of the numbers of the divergence, just to do back-of-the-envelope calculations

Comment: @dmckee, actually, scratch that, i don't want to artifically limit the scope or the domain of the answers: in fact, any sort of proposed beaming technology using any combination of mirrors and fresnel lens is acceptable if it offers a better range. I'm interested particularly in mirrors because fresnel lens alone only work in tight angles around the radial direction, limiting the directions where the power can be beamed

Comment: For coherent light, assuming a circular beam, diffraction puts a lower limit on divergence of $2.4 \lambda \over D$ where $\lambda$ is wavelength and $D$ is beam diameter.

Comment: In general the angular spread of the radiation is the Fraunhofer transform of the near field. For simple near fields, this is analytically computable. In the case of a circular beam, the precise result is $\propto \frac{J_1(\pi x)}{\pi x} $ where $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. This has its first zero at $x=\pm 1.2$, which is the source of the 2.4 in my previous comment.

Comment: @ColinK, so what i gather from this is that, a 1 meter wide beam of $10^{-6}$m wavelength will have a divergence angle of $10^{-6}$, and at the target, a distance S away (far field limit), will produce a beam spread over $10^{-6} S$ meter, so for S=$10^{12}$ meters, that is equal $10^{6}$ meters, a million times the original beam width. If i increase the source beam from 1 meter to $10^{3}$ meters, the divergence angle improves to $10^{-9}$, which at the same distance will spread $10^{3}$ meters? that is, just twice the original beam width?

Comment: If i increase the source beam to $10^4$ m, the spread becomes just $10^2$ meter at the target, but it is slightly worse overall. So, If the above is true, then there is an optimal source beam width for a given distance and wavelength? *clarification: where optimal means that the size of the target collector is minimised*

Comment: Lurscher, yes, the optimum is when the source beam width is the square root of the distance to the target, when all distances/sizes are measured in wavelengths.

Comment: @JimGraber, thanks for the clarification. What if the laser has a focusing element at the source with an incredibly long focal length of $10^{18}$ wavelengths? is that unattainable by engineering reasons or by fundamental physics limits?

Comment: So I will think about your question and try to answer it in a day or two.  In the meantime, you can find useful information by googling "Airy disk"  and "diffraction limited".  You might also try looking up the difference between "ray optics" and "wave optics" or "physical optics".

Comment: My first thought is yes, you do want a focal length of $10^{18}$ wavelengths. Then you also need your laser beam to be $10^9$ wavelengths wide. Your lens will also need to be that wide. You will then get an Airy disk with 80% of the light that is only 2.4 $10^9$ wavelengths in diameter at the focus, $10^{18}$ wavelengths away. If you try to make your lens or your laser smaller, diffraction will defeat you, and your Airy disk at the focus will get bigger.

Answer (score 2):

As comments point out, a far field focus is subject to a "diffraction limit" which subtends an angle (in radians) of roughly $w/D$, where $w$ is wavelength of radiation and $D$ is diameter of the mirror, whether the focal length is finite or not. Let's call this angle $A$. A beam reflected from the mirror initially has diameter $D$ but at a far distance $S$, the beam width will be $AS$ and dominated by diffraction. This is somewhat counter intuitive, because a smaller far beam requires a wider initial beam. You can get an approximate optimal value of $D$ for smallest spot by calculating the point where $D=AS$, which yields $D=\sqrt{wS}$ - a result mentioned in comments.

$D=\sqrt{wS}$ also applies to the optimal diameter of the pinhole in a pinhole camera for maximum resolution, where $S$ is distance to film/sensor.